# Uploading a react project to netlify for continuous deployment but getting error in build

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am trying to upload this react project to netlify for continuous deployment. I used create-react-app. My build is failing and I don't know how to fix it. So i'll attach netlify's response, my repo and netlify's default build settings that i'm using. Any help would be appreciated thank you :)
[Github repo](https://github.com/ohersi1/CryptoAppReact)[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/456HJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr43H.png)

I was expecting to upload my react project to netlify for continuous deployment and it has worked before with different projects but I am having difficulties today.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.